# Laravel 5.4 Reset Email Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

This is my reset.blade.php file.

```
@extends('main')
@section('title',"| Forgot My Password ")

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['url'=>'password/reset','method'=>'POST']) !!}

                        {{ Form::label('email','Email Address:') }}
                        {{ Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}

                        {{Form::submit('Reset Password',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) }}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
@endsection
```

When i enter the email field, it returns 2 validation errors;

Errors:
The token field is required.
The password field is required.

I dont know where the erros are. There are not any field and password fields in this form? Help!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you show us the code of the controller?

Comment: show code of this method `password/reset`

Comment: I solved that errors but When i click the reset button it shows me "Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpoEw.png